# Value of type NSDate has no member inUTCRegion() - Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsdate, utc

I am converting my swift 2 project over and it throws this error:

```
Value of type NSDate has no member inUTCRegion()
```

I am calling it like so:

```
var date:NSDate = NSDate()
date.inUTCRegion().UTCDate
```

What's the equivalent in swift 3?

Comment: There is no `inUTCRegion()` method of `(NS)Date` even in Swift 2. Apparently you are using a third-party library or a custom extension. By the way: Don't use `NSDate` in Swift 3. There is a native struct `Date`.

Comment: Thanks @vadian, just stepped through the podfile and pinpointed the library.  thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the purpose of that method? `Date()` (and `NSDate()`) are already UTC.